# Unknown error when uploading file to ftp server

Tags: ios, ftp

I am trying to upload an image file to the server. I am applying the example from https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon

Here is the code:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hotel1.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);

    WRRequestUpload * uploadImage = [[WRRequestUpload alloc] init];
    uploadImage.delegate = (id)self;

    //for anonymous login just leave the username and password nil
    uploadImage.hostname = @"***.***.***.***";
    uploadImage.username = @"-------";
    uploadImage.password = @"-------";

    //we set our data
    uploadImage.sentData = imageData;

    //the path needs to be absolute to the FTP root folder.
    //full URL would be ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/space.jpg
    uploadImage.path = @"/android_images/image.jpg";

    //we start the request
    [uploadImage start];
```

but it gives error -[WRRequestListDirectory stream:handleEvent:] [Line 1004] Unknown error!

am I missing anything. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ? I am also having the same problem

Comment: Dhanesh how you solved this issue.Please guide us.Thanks

Comment: @Shailesh, did you found the reason for issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in the uploadimage.hostname property  try skipping the ftp:// part and enter the host address alone  for eg: "qwerty.com" instead of "ftp://qwerty.com" ,  it solved for me, and make sure that the authentication details given are correct. cheers !!

Comment: I wrote Blackraccoon and johnric is absolutely correct. Since this is passed down to Apple's code, you really need to have the ftp:// or Apple tosses it's cookies with, as you see, a message that makes little sense.

Note the comment just above your line says **full URL would be `ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/space.jpg`** which is your hint that **ftp://** is required. Cheers!

Comment: no its not working.I gave host name as uploadImage.hostname = @"132.1.7.34";

Answer (score 0):

if you are using BlackRaccoon,

Please make one line change in `BRRequest.m` file.

In `- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<BRRequestDelegate>)aDelegate` Function.
Change

```
self.passiveMode = YES;
```

to

```
self.passiveMode = NO;
```

And it will work....

That change worked for me.